# How can I detect overlapping characters / diacritics in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, text, software-recommendation, layout

Is there any tool, script, or plug-in for InDesign or Acrobat Pro that would detect or highlight overlapping characters or diacritics? See sample below:

[image: overlapping characters/diacritics]

Comment: I don't think there is. It's all simply leading values. InDesign doesn't "detect" overlapping standard characters if the leading values are too small.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is none and never will be. I my native language (Latvian) there is also some cases, when I would like to have this possibility. But much easier way is to make a sting of capitals with diacritics and copy it in two lines (again, Latvian alphabet): ĒŖŪĪŌĀŠĢĶĻŽČŅ. Then check leading with lower values from alphabet: qypģjķļņ. That's it - you have a correct leading.